# What browsers support the function _now()?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am using a jquery plugin that works in latest firefox and IE 11 but fails in Ie9.  I just debugged it and it appears that IE9 is failing on the line:

```
var curr = _now();
```

where IE9 said it doesn't recognize _now();

Where can i see what browsers support this function?  is there any suggestions to replace the line above that will work including IE9?

Comment: var curr=new Date();

Comment: where is it defined? Nothing in native javascript uses a `_` prefix for functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **no browsers** that natively implement `_now`.

To get the current date, use

```
var current = new Date();
```

To [get the current timestamp and support older JavaScript implementations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Polyfill), use

```
var current = (new Date()).getTime();
```

To [get the current timestamp for ES5 and above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), use

```
var current = Date.now();
```

---

Any further issues will be exclusively related to the plugin you are using. It defines `_now` and does it in a way that IE9 cannot process. If you **absolutely must** keep using the plugin, you will need to figure out why that specific plugin is breaking.